# How to remove time in second after retrieve from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this label retrieve time from database and display in label. but time in database also consist of second for example 03:45:29, how can i remove the time in second to become 03:45 in the label after retrieve it. this is my code:`LabelDateMarker.Text = LabelDateMarker.Text + " " + dr[3].ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a format string for this

```
((DateTime)dr[3]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

instead of

```
dr[3].ToString();
```

For more information have a look at the available formats at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would probably suggest using `HH:mm` instead of `hh:mm`.

Comment: this appear error which is "no overload for method toString takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @JonSkeet good idea, changed it
@FATINHAZWANI so your dr[3] value isn't a `DateTime`? Which type is it?

Comment: You are calling ToString on an object type. Object has no overload of ToString that accepts a format string.

Comment: i retrieve it from database. it datetime and the value in column is like "2017-05-05 15:08:34" i want to cut the :34 so that in label it become "2017-05-05 15:08"

Comment: @FATINHAZWANI: Your question provided no indication that you wanted the date, along with no indication of the type of `dr`. Please clarify the question. This is where a [mcve] comes in handy.

Comment: It works when i change the previous one with this. thankyou gais !

Comment: @FATINHAZWANI: Note that you really, really should use the invariant culture, if you always want this to be formatted in the Gregorian calendar system (which I suggest you almost certainly do).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `dr` is a `SqlDataReader` or similar, you probably want to cast to `DateTime`, then format the value appropriately:

```
DateTime dateTime = (DateTime) dr[3];
string formatted = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
LabelDateMarker.Text += " " + formatted;
```

Here `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` is a [custom date/time format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) indicating that you want the hours and minutes after the ISO-8601-formatted date part.

I've used the invariant culture when formatting to avoid this giving unexpected results in locales that don't use the Gregorian calendar by default.

(I've assumed the value is always non-null. If it might be null, you should check it with `dr.IsDBNull(3)` first.)

Comment: what if the time in the database is `null`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: If that's a concern, the OP should check for that first using `dr.IsDBNull(3)`. That's outside the scope of what this question is about though, IMO.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't think it's outside of scope for this question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I think we'll have to agree to disagree about that - the OP certainly never mentioned seeing `System.DBNull` in the output, or anything similar. But I've mentioned `IsDBNull` at the end of my answer now anyway.

Comment: Well, The question itself seems to suggest the OP is kind of a newbie when it comes to this, so they might not even be aware of the fact that it might be `DBNull` in the first place. This is why I believe it is in the scope of this question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Again, I think we'll have to agree to disagree. Do you think that answers should also cope with the possibility of `LabelDateMarker` being null, or `dr` being null, or the index 3 not being appropriate for the indexer? What about the value being non-null but not a `DateTime`? There's an awful lot that *could* go wrong with code like this, but without any indication whatsoever that the OP is in any of these situations, I think it's better to focus on what's actually been asked.